# Git Fetch - with specfic user's ssh key

Tags: git, github, ssh

On my server I have my personal user and I have another application user(app).

I'm su to the (app) user I setup my git remote origin - my git conf file now looks like this:

```
cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.example.com:example/mysite.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Problem being is that in order to ssh into git it needs to use my personal ssh key under my user (not under the app user) - how is this usually handled? creating a new ssh key for my (app) user doesn't seem great - is there a config way thats understood to point to my users .ssh/key?

Comment: I used a ssh config to assign a specific key to a url.

Comment: But that ssh config will need to be under my app user and points to a key under my personal.ssh? I don’t think permissions will allow that

Answer (score 1):

> But that ssh config will need to be under my app user and points to a key under my personal.ssh? I don’t think permissions will allow that

Then you need to create a dedicated key, for app user to access the remote repository with the right account.
That still involves a ~app/.ssh/config file, in order to use the right (new) SSH key

```
 Host ghperso
   Hostname github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/dedicatedKey
```

And the URL would then be:

```
git remote set-url origin ghperso:example/mysite.git
```